# Why does session.merge throw IntegrityError when row contains null when default and server_default are set

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am trying to update a record by using `session.merge(object)` when a field is set as not nullable with a sqlalchemy and server default. An error is thrown that the not null constraint has been violated when it tries to update an existing record. I was able to get around it by dropping null values from the records in the table initialization, but this seems weird. Is this to be expected or do I not understand how server defaults or `session.merge` works?

Python version: 3.6.8

sqlalchemy version: 1.3.4

Example code:

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base 

Base = declarative_base()       

class TestTable(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'test_table'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    field = sa.Column(sa.String, default='Unknown', server_default=sa.text("'Unknown'"), nullable=False)
    field2 = sa.Column(sa.Integer)

engine = sa.create_engine('postgresql://postgres@localhost/test')

Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

session = sa.orm.sessionmaker(engine)() 

record = {'id': 1, 'field': None, 'field2': 3}
session.merge(TestTable(**record))

session.commit()

session.merge(TestTable(**record))

session.commit()
```

Error thrown:

```
IntegrityError: (psycopg2.errors.NotNullViolation) null value in column "field" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (1, null, 3).

[SQL: UPDATE test_table SET field=%(field)s WHERE test_table.id = %(test_table_id)s]
[parameters: {'field': None, 'test_table_id': 1}]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/gkpj)
```

Answer (score 2):

At the time of your first merge, the row doesn't exist, so it is created:

```py
record = {'id': 1, 'field': None, 'field2': 3}
session.merge(TestTable(**record))
```

...emits:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (id, field, field2) VALUES (%(id)s, %(field)s, %(field2)s)
{'id': 1, 'field': 'Unknown', 'field2': 3}
```

Per [the documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.default), the `default` parameter to `Column` is applied on *insert* which is why you can see that `None` has been replaced by `'Unknown'` in the parameter set sent along with the insert statement. The docs state:

> A scalar, Python callable, or `ColumnElement` expression representing
>   the default value for this column, which will be invoked upon insert
>   if this column is otherwise not specified in the VALUES clause of the
>   insert.

...so in this case, it seems that "not specified" should be interpreted as "not `None`", as you clearly have "specified" the value in your `record` dict. Relevant to this is that when you instantiate an instance without offering any values for any attributes, those attributes implicitly hold a value of `None` already:

```py
print(TestTable().field is None)  # True
```

If you remove the `default=...` kwarg from your column definition, even though you supply `field=None` to your `TestTable` constructor, with the default value removed, no value for that parameter is sent through to the database at all:

```sql
INSERT INTO test_table (id, field2) VALUES (%(id)s, %(field2)s)
{'id': 1, 'field2': 3}
```

In this case, the server side default would trigger. So before flush of an insert statement, SQLAlchemy will swap any `None` values of columns that have a client side default to the specified value.

On your second merge, the row already exists in the database, so the values of the merged instance are populated on the instance that represents the row that already exists in the database. During the merge the value of the `field` column on that instance is changed from `'Unknown'` to `None`. This change of value means that the new value of that field will be sent through to the database as part of an *update* query. Note that neither the client side or server side defaults apply to an update statement.

```sql
UPDATE test_table SET field=%(field)s WHERE test_table.id = %(test_table_id)s
{'field': None, 'test_table_id': 1}
```

As we attempt to explicitly set a `NOT NULL` column to `NULL`, the `IntegrityError` is raised.

Comment: Thank you for a very detailed response! That was very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with sqlalchemy, but it seems to me the problem is you've misunderstood the function of default values in table definitions. A specified default **is not**  substituted for null. The default value is substituted on an insert when the column is not in the list of values or an insert/update when the key word DEFAULT is used. As example try the following in psql (sorry I cannot convert to sqlalchemy):

```
 create table txx (id serial, col1 text, col2 text default 'xxx'); 
 insert into txx(col1) values ('abcd');
 insert into txx(col1,col2) values ('defg',null), ('hijk', DEFAULT);
 select *  from txx;

 update txx set col2 = DEFAULT where col2 is null;
 select *  from txx;
```

On the other hand NOT NULL constraint is always applied. Further NON NULL constraint and DEFAULT value are totally independent of each other.  Hope this helps.